# Multithreading in rust

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, system, scheduler

I'm currently learning rust and want to make a scheduler as part of my learning process. I almost finish it but having problem when I want to run the task that I register in my scheduler as a background process, here's my code:

```
// An attribute to hide warnings for unused code.
#![allow(dead_code)]

use std::time::{Duration, SystemTime};
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Unit {
    Seconds,
    Minutes,
    Hours
}

struct Scheduler {
    logger: String,
    jobs: Vec<Job>
}

struct Job {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    every: u64,
    unit: Unit,
    task: Box<dyn Fn() -> () + Send + Sync>, // Box is used when we want to use heap reference instead of stack 
    registered_at: SystemTime
}

impl Scheduler {
    fn new(logger: String) -> Self {
        Scheduler {
            logger: logger,
            jobs: Vec::<Job>::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_job(&mut self, job: Job) {
        self.jobs.push(Job {
            id: job.id,
            name: job.name,
            every: job.every,
            unit: job.unit,
            task: Box::new(job.task),
            registered_at: job.registered_at
        });
    }

    fn get_jobs(&self) {
    }

    fn start(&self) {
        loop {
            for job in &self.jobs {
                std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                Self::should_run(job)
            }
        }
    }

    fn should_run(job: &Job) {
        match job.registered_at.elapsed() {
            Ok(elapsed) => {
                if elapsed.as_secs()%job.every == 0 {
                    let j = job;
                    // Create a new thread and run the background function in it.
                    thread::spawn(move || {
                        // This closure will be run on a separate thread
                        // run the closure here
                        (j.task)()
                    });
                }
            }
            Err(e) => {
                // an error occurred!
                println!("Error: {e:?}");
            }
        };
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let mut sch = Scheduler::new(String::from("logger"));
    
    sch.add_job(Job { 
        id: 1,
        name: String::from("downloading report"),
        every: 1,
        unit: Unit::Seconds,
        task: Box::new(|| {
            // This is the first task. It will be executed every 1 seconds.
            println!("downloading...");
        }),
        registered_at: SystemTime::now()
    });

    sch.start();

}
```

I got this error:

```
  --> src/main.rs:65:21
   |
59 |       fn should_run(job: &Job) {
   |                     ---  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |                     |
   |                     `job` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
...
65 | /                     thread::spawn(move || {
66 | |                         // This closure will be run on a separate thread
67 | |                         // run the closure here
68 | |                         (j.task)()
69 | |                     });
   | |                      ^
   | |                      |
   | |______________________`job` escapes the associated function body here
   |                        argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here since I'm new to rust.

Thank you.

I'm expecting j.task() to be executed asynchronously.

Comment: `job.clone()` just creates another reference, your `Job` does not implement `Clone`.

Comment: Because `Job` doesn't implement `Clone`, the call `job.clone()` is cloning the reference (so that `j : &'1 Job` and NOT `j : Job` as you expect). The bigger trouble here is it would appear you want to clone a `dyn Fn() -> ()` which isn't allowed (you might want to replace `task` with a generic)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah sorry .clone() was a mistake, I remove it and it still give me same error

Comment: The `job` reference is only alive for lifetime `'1`, but since its passed into the closure held by the thread, that reference must live potentially forever (because thread spawning has no guarantee of promptness, and that method may actually run a year in the future), and so the lifetime `'1` must be at least as long as the "forever" lifetime (this is what "argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`" means). Probably the simplest solution is to use `jobs: Vec<Arc<Job>>` and `clone` + `move` into the thread as before.

Comment: @user2407038 ah nice its working using Arc, thank you very much. one more question, will the cloned variable be freed after it finish the execution?

Comment: `Arc` lets you share ownership of a value, in your case the value will be freed after the thread is done running and the `Scheduler` is freed. For more details on exactly why and when the cloned variable will be freed, I suggest that you read the documentation for Arc.

Comment: just read it, I understand now that Clone will create new reference pointer for the location of a value in the memory heap and increase reference count. should I be worried about my case? because everytime the scheduler run the task it will create new reference pointer and increase the reference count, will it caused memory leak? or it will be safe bcs the reference pointer variable that I create with Clone will be freed after it finish its execution?